# finding $y$ $(xy^2+y)dx+(x^2y-x)dy=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$(xy^2+y)dx+(x^2y-x)dy=0$$

$$y(xy+1)+x(xy-1)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

$z=xy+1\Rightarrow y=\frac{z}{x}-1\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dz}{dx}x-z}{x^2}$

$z-2=xy-1$

$$\frac{z^2}{x}-z+(xz-2x)(\frac{\frac{dz}{dx}x-z}{x^2})=0$$

$$\frac{z^2}{x}-z+\frac{zdz}{xdx}-z^2{x}^{3}-zx-\frac{2dz}{xdx}+2x=0$$

it only seems to get compliced, how should I continue?

Comment: The mistake starts here :  $z=xy+1\implies y=\frac{z}{x}-1$ which should be $y=\frac{z-1}{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start using $$y=\frac z x\qquad y'=\frac{z'}{x}-\frac{z}{x^2}$$ the differential equation becomes $$(z-1) z'+\frac{2 z}{x}=0$$ which seems to be easily workable since you can write it as  $$x'=-\frac{x (z-1)}{2 z}$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

If you go to the end, you would have the opportunity to admire a beautiful function.

**Edit**

Since Nikunj provided a god solution and the answer, let us finish 
 $$x'=-\frac{x (z-1)}{2 z}\implies 2\log(x)+C=\log (z)-z\implies Cx^2=ze^{-z}$$ and using [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$z=-W\left(-C x^2\right)\implies y=-\frac{W\left(-C x^2\right)}{x}$$

Comment: where did $x'$ came from? do not we need to get to an equation of the form $\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{dx}{x}$? can we use $\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$?
Thanks

Comment: $(z-1) z'+\frac{2 z}{x}=0$ is separable. $x'=\frac{dx}{dz}$

Answer (score 1):

This can be written as:
$$xy(ydx+xdy)+ydx-xdy=0$$
Now, divide by $y^2$
$$\implies \frac{x}{y}d(xy)+d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=0$$
$$\implies d(xy)=-\frac{y}{x}d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$
Integrating both sides, we get:
$$xy=-\ln \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+C$$

Comment: How did the integration got to $-ln(\frac{x}{y})$? what about the $-\frac{y}{x}$?

Comment: This is $$\int \frac{d(\frac{x}{y})}{\frac xy}$$ Now treat $\frac xy$ as one variable.

Comment: @Nikunj Sir can you pls tell me how did u write 1st step : given equation is different right?